# Substitute variable with another variable using s/

Tags: perl

I have the following hash structure

```
test =>  '/var/tmp $slot'

my $slot_number = 0;  # just another variable.
```

I then fetch the value of the key and store in a variable called $test_command

Now I need to replace `$slot` in `$test_command` with another variable called `$slot_number`
So I am trying this

```
$test_command =~ s/$slot/$slot_number/g;  this does not work

$test_command =~ s/$slot/$slot_number/ee; does not work

$test_command =~ s/\$slot/\$slot_number/g; this does not work
```

Expected output should be

```
$test_command = /var/tmp 0
```

Comment: Had you used `use strict;`, you would have known that `s/$slot/.../` was trying to interpolate a variable. Always use `use warnings; use strict;`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this?  `$test_command=~s/\$slot/$slot_number/g;`

This code:

```
my $slot_number = 5;
my $test_command = '/var/tmp $slot';
$test_command=~s/\$slot/$slot_number/g;
print "$test_command\n";
```

Prints:

`/var/tmp 5`

You don't want to escape the second variable if you want to replace it with the value.

Answer (score 1):

You're so close!  See if the following will do what you want:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $test_command = '/var/tmp $slot';
my $slot_number = 0;

$test_command =~ s/\$slot/$slot_number/;

print $test_command;
```

**Output**:

```
/var/tmp 0
```